# checkbox to php database

Tags: php, database, forms, checkbox

Hi I am working on an assignment to input 3 checked items into my database. I can't use arrays for this.

Here is my form:

```
 <p>What are your categories of interest? (Select as many as you'd 
 like below)</p>
 <input name="industry" type="checkbox" value="industry" 
 />Industry<br />
 <input name="technical" type="checkbox" value="technical" 
 />Technical<br />
 <input name="career" type="checkbox" value="career" />Career<br />
```

Here is my php:

```
$name = $_POST["name"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$industry = $_POST["industry"];
$technical = $_POST["technical"];
$career = $_POST["career"];
$role = $_POST["role"];

include("includes/dbconfig.php");

$stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO `contacts` (`contactid`, `name`, 
`email`, `industry`, `technical`, `career` `role`) VALUES (NULL, 
'$name', '$email', '$industry', '$technical', '$career', 
'$role');");

$stmt->execute();

header("location:contactthankyou.php");



?>
```

and my database table has 3 columns (industry, technical, career).

NOTHING WORKS please help

I tried this:

```
if(! isset($_POST["industry"]))
{$industry = "notchecked";

}else{
$industry = $_POST["industry"];}
```

It did not work...

And this:

```
$industry = false;
if( isset($_POST["industry"])) 
{
  $industry = true;
}
```

Comment: You've failed your condition of "_I can't use arrays for this._" by using any `$_POST` value, as that is an array.

Comment: There is code missing here; where is the rest of the HTML/form?

Comment: <form action="process-contact.php" method="POST">
        <p>What are your categories of interest? (Select as many as you'd like below) .       </p>
        <input name="industry" type="checkbox" value="industry" />Industry<br />
        <input name="technical" type="checkbox" value="technical" />Technical<br />
        <input name="career" type="checkbox" value="career" />Career<br />
        <input type="submit" />
      </form>

Comment: In the question. Noone can read code in a comment

Comment: Basically, a checkbox field is only sent to the PHP IF it is checked. So you have to first test for its existance like `if ( isset($_POST['industry']) ){ // then it was checked`

Answer (score -1):

you need to check which checkboxes are checked before save them. and than you need to give them a value, if not checked. Apply this code for each of them.
For example:

```
if(!isset($_POST["industry"])){

$industry = "notchecked";

}else{
$industry = $_POST["industry"];

}
```

Comment: Where does this go? Does it replace the php where I have $industry = $_POST["industry"];

Comment: I think that should be `if( ! isset($_POST["industry"]) ){`